# PHP: Regex: Match if doesnt contain

Tags: php, regex

I have two urls (below). I need to match the one that doesn't contain the "story" part in the it. I know i need to use negative lookhead/behind, but i cant for the life of me get it to work

**Urls**

```
news/tech/story/2014/oct/28/apple-iphone/261736

news/tech/2014/oct/28/apple-iphone/261736
```

**Current Regex**

```
news\/([a-z0-9-\/]{1,255})(\d{4})\/(\w{3})\/(\d{2})\/([a-z0-9\-]{1,50})\/(\d{1,10})
```

**Example:**

http://regex101.com/r/jC7jC4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one :

```
news\/(([a-z0-9-\/](?!story)){1,255})(\d{4})\/(\w{3})\/(\d{2})\/([a-z0-9\-]{1,50})\/(\d{1,10})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **negative lookahead** like this:

```
(?!.*\bstory\b)news\/([a-z0-9-\/]{1,255})(\d{4})\/(\w{3})\/(\d{2})\/([a-z0-9\-]{1,50})\/(\d{1,10})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC7jC4/3)

`(?!.*\bstory\b)` is **negative lookahead** that will stop match if there is a word `story` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with strpos() if you don't have to use regex

```
 if (strpos($url, 'story') === false
```

Comment: Agreed. While negative assertions can do the job, the old saw about having two problems now applies especially well to situations like this, IMO. Future maintainers would thank you if you can pair the regex with some string operations that make the behaviour a little more clear.